# Replacing obsolete photodarlington with phototransistor

Tags: infrared, phototransistor, photosensor

I've got an old circuit design I need to replicate, function wise, to fit into an existing larger design.  Logic I can usually handle,  anything with transistors starts to get me lost.  My strength is in DFM and manufacturing, not necessarily electrical design.  The original design functions as a simple on-off switch on a TTL logic circuit, with a separate IR LED source.  Top circuit is the original design, bottom is my proposed alternate.

D1 is a photodarlington, Motorola MRD370, long obsolete and difficult to find at a decent price.  Due to cost and availability I'd like to use a phototransistor instead of a photodarlington, but am concerned about enough gain.  Hence the 2nd schematic with an additional 2N3904.  Resistance value I haven't even tried to calculate yet.  The original circuit is a TTL logic circuit, just can't figure out how to show that in the schematic.   I have enough activity to post links now, so here's the original schematic I'm working from.  Identical circuit is duplicated a few more times on the board, each for an independent photodarlington.
[image: http://www.siegecraft.us/images/IMGP5973.JPG]

Would my proposed circuit be completely off the mark here?  Photosensors are totally outside my practical experience.  Switching time really isn't a big concern here, as the circuit is detecting the presence/absence of a stationary object.   I added a 2nd proposed circuit, based on suggestions received.  Left the first one to hopefully avoid confusion with changes.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f45H7I.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Are you sure about that first one? It doesn't look right.

Comment: D1 and D2 are photodiodes.

Comment: In this schematic, yes,  I used photodiodes. I didn't see an available option for phototransistors or photodarlingtons.  The original circuit left the base leg unconnected.    I'll double check that first circuit,  the original schematic is pretty difficult to read, and I can't post photos yet.

Comment: Verified the schematic on the first one again.  I agree, it really does look odd to me as well, but I did confirm it via both an original schematic and also measurements on a PCB.  That's part of my confusion, the original is just not what my research has turned up for a photodiode circuit of any kind.

Comment: Yeah you’re almost right photo diode is backwards it’s a current source when reverse biased

Comment: So, essentially, just flip D2 around?   Just put in a revised schematic to show that change.

Comment: Something is really wrong in the first (also the second) schematic. Q1 will certainly burn in the first moment, the second circuit does nothing.Could you send pictures instead ? Of the original circuit.

Comment: Are you shure there is a 9V source or it's just the voltage you measured there?

Comment: No, definitely not 9v,  it's a TTL logic source.  Again, limitation of the schematic software, never used it before.  Hopefully this works to clarify.  I'll edit the image link into the main post as well.  http://www.siegecraft.us/images/IMGP5973.JPG

Comment: Normally NPN bias current is sourced from the Vcc so reverse biased from Vcc to base.  or many other ways too https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-ab&tbm=isch&q=Photodiode+amp&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiDscuxxYPbAhVH_IMKHddaA1kQBQg3KAA&biw=1142&bih=991&dpr=0.92

Comment: @Hans You say there are several similar sections, only one of which you are showing us. I can't tell from reading your writing what the original purpose of the circuit is. For all I know, it might be a paper-tape reader from 1970. Would you mind spending a little time talking about the "design I need to replicate, function wise?"

Comment: I can definitely share the use for this one. It's 4-switch opto board, used in the ball trough of a pinball machine.  Detects how many balls are in the trough.  Ties into, I believe, a 6521 or 6821 peripheral interface adapter (PIA) chip.  All 4 circuits are identical.  I could do the whole schematic as well,  but the font is hard to read, so wanted to zoom in closer.

Comment: For more in-depth background, www.pinrepair.com/6803/index.htm#opto will show the exact boards in question,   and should answer most questions on how this board is used.

Answer (score 1):

I made some corrections according to the picture you posted.

There is nothing special about this phototransistor in the way is used here.

The higher current parameter ( up to 20 mA) is not used here since the bias resistor has a high value.

Simply use a normal phototransistor like [BPW76](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/vishay-semiconductor-opto-division/BPW76A/751-1018-ND/1681152) instead with the original schematic. It is pin to pin compatible.

Comment: That's even better.  Means I can just use the existing boards to test as well.  This way I'm only dealing with a single variable. Much appreciated.